# Proof of Inclusion-Exclusion principle without induction

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

I understand the proof of the principle using induction. But as people argue against induction that guessing the formula in the first place is not so easy, I am trying to prove it without induction.

I used basic principles (steps below) to get to the answer but then after a few steps it gets tricky. Also it would take n steps to get to the answer. So I'm guessing that we would eventually need to find a pattern and apply induction. Would appreciate any help on how I can move forward with this.

$$ P ( \cup_{i=1}^{n} (A_i)) = \Sigma_{i=1}^n ( P(A_i) - P(A_i \cap ( \cup_{j<i} A_j ) ) ) $$

$$ P(A_i \cap ( \cup_{j<i} A_j ) ) = P( \cup_{j<i} ( A_i\cap A_j)) = \Sigma_{j<i} ( P(A  _i \cap A_j) - P( (A_i \cap A_j) \cap ( \cup_{k<j} ( P(A_i \cap A_k ))  $$

Comment: You prove something starting from some assumptions. If you have some metamathematical restrictions, like not using induction, it would be useful to make it clear what can be used. Note also that since the statement that you want to prove has a "for all natural number $n$", the assumptions should be able to produce statements like that. In many proofs it is induction the axiom that eventually provides that "for all natural number $n$".

Comment: "*But as people argue against induction*"... Who argues against using induction?  That is like arguing against gravity or the globe-earth.  Such complaints can and should be ignored.